# Upload CSV Google Analytics Data File c#

Tags: c#, csv, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to upload a CSV file to google analytics using C#. Theirs an example on the google developers site here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/cost-data-import#custom_data_source

However, it uses python. Im trying to rewrite it using C#, but it isn't turning out as easy as I thought. any help?

Don't know how to implement the media from the code sample from the site either, so "csvToUpload" isn't actually doing anything. (csvToUpload is the csv file directory).

Code Snippet:

```
public void UploadCSVFile(string csvToUpload, string uploadDate, string accountID, string webPropertyID, string dataSourceID)
    {   

        FileStream stream2 = new FileStream(csvToUpload, FileMode.Open);

        ManagementResource.DailyUploadsResource.UploadMediaUpload dailyUploads = service.Management.DailyUploads.Upload(accountID, webPropertyID,
            dataSourceID, uploadDate, 1, ManagementResource.DailyUploadsResource.UploadMediaUpload.TypeEnum.Cost, stream2, "Data Test");

        dailyUploads.Reset = true;
        //dailyUploads.UploadAsync();
        dailyUploads.Upload();
        stream2.Close();
    }
```

Wanted to update the code, and the post to see if anyone could help me out, here's updated code for this quest.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What specific thing do you need help on? How is your code snippet not doing what you want it to do?

Comment: Assuming you saw the link, in the example you're suppose to add the CSV to execute... however, they method they used to add it is in python, and i can't find any C# examples to follow. plus i can't find the right calls for it...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Upload has a second one that lets you send a stream.  Load your csv file as a stream and try and send it that way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, I've tried that too, however it gives me a "cannot implicity convert" request. So i try to change it to adjust it, but i start to get several errors after that.
[link](http://hastebin.com/furucahoyu.avrasm)
theirs the link. I have commented the one above it too, i just left them both their as a visual difference. I know the account webproperty and datasource are correct. i can pull data from GA, im just trying to send to it.

Comment: I will see if I can put together an example, or a tutorial for you.

Comment: ah, that would be great, I still haven't found a c# related example of this, but I know you make great tutorials. I've used them before.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's just too late, but for other people, this code works fine:

```
// Read file to stream
FileStream dataStream = new FileStream(AppWindow.WindowBag["File"].ToString(), FileMode.Open);
// Upload selected file
ManagementResource.DailyUploadsResource.UploadMediaUpload request = AppWindow.Service.Management.DailyUploads.Upload(AppWindow.WindowBag["Account"].ToString(),
                                            AppWindow.WindowBag["Property"].ToString(),
                                            AppWindow.WindowBag["Dataset"].ToString(),
                                            "2014-04-14",
                                            1,
                                            ManagementResource.DailyUploadsResource.UploadMediaUpload.TypeEnum.Cost,
                                            dataStream, "application/octet-stream");
request.Reset = true;
request.ProgressChanged += request_ProgressChanged;
request.ResponseReceived += request_ResponseReceived;
request.Upload();
dataStream.Close();
```